# dropdown value reverts to default value after selected php

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I am trying to create a dropdown using php. I am using the onchange="this.form.submit();" as part of the code. I would like to display the result on the same page.

After I select the dropdown value, the value displays, but the selected value reverts back to the first value.

```
   <form action="" method="post">
   <select name="q" onchange="this.form.submit();">
   <option value="0" >Select One</option>
   <option value="1" >One</option>
   <option value="2" >Two</option>
   <option value="3" >Three</option>
   <option value="4" >Four</option>
   <option value="5" >Five</option>
   </select>
   </form>

 <?php 
 if (isset($_POST['q'])) {echo 'var is now set to ' . $_POST['q'];}
 ?>
```

I would like to display the select value and echo the value too. Thanks for all you help!

Comment: does the page reload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `selected` property if that value has been selected, just do it by:

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <select name="q" onchange="this.form.submit();">
   <option value="0" <?php if(isset($_POST['q']) && $_POST['q']=="0") echo "selected"?>>Select One</option>
   <option value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['q']) && $_POST['q']=="1") echo "selected"?> >One</option>
   <option value="2" <?php if(isset($_POST['q']) && $_POST['q']=="2") echo "selected"?>>Two</option>
   <option value="3" <?php if(isset($_POST['q']) && $_POST['q']=="3") echo "selected"?>>Three</option>
   <option value="4" <?php if(isset($_POST['q']) && $_POST['q']=="4") echo "selected"?>>Four</option>
   <option value="5" <?php if(isset($_POST['q']) && $_POST['q']=="5") echo "selected"?>>Five</option>
  </select>  
</form>
```

Comment: For sure a working solution but inefficient code, i recommend an array based solution, easier to read and follows the simply rule DRY - don't repeat yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much! The code worked for what I needed it for...I will try the array approach next. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The other answers work but testing each single option is inefficient. Do something like this:

```
<?php
    // put all your options into an array
    $options = array(0 => 'Select One', 1 => 'First', 2 => 'Second', 3 => 'And so on');
?>
<select name="q" onchange="this.form.submit();">
<?php
    // loop trough the elements
    foreach($options as $value => $label) {
        // test if the current value is the posted one...
        $selected = (isset($_POST['q']) && intval($_POST['q']) === $value) ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; 
        echo '<option value="'.$value.'"'.$selected.'>'.$label.'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="1" <?php if ($_POST['q']=="1") {echo "selected";}?> >One</option>
```

Add this code all option, but you must use arrays for this, because my way is long way.